# Can anyone explain me this circuit?

Tags: relay, home-automation, ldr

I am trying to make a laser trip alarm circuit and found one on Electro-schematics.com,attached it the receiver circuit.I cann't understand the use of the relay(RL1) as there is a switch already available near supply.Also i would like to as that when the laser light will not fall on the circuit what would happen and where can i connect a buzzer or led so it can notify me the same.I know this is a lot to ask,but please spare some time for me.
The circuit-[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDR stands for *Light Dependent Resistor*.  These things are usually quite sensitive in that the resistance varies over a decade or from sunlight to dark.

The LDR and R2 form a voltage divider.  R2 is fixed, so when light hits the LDR, its resistance is low the voltage out of the divider is low.  This keeps the SCR off.

When the light goes away, the voltage out of the divider goes up, which triggers the SCR, which turns on the relay.  Once a SCR is triggered, it will stay triggered as long as current thru it is maintained.  The relay does this.  The effect is that the relay will turn on when the LDR is first exposed to dark, then stay on until manually reset by opening switch S1.

D2 is to provide a safe path for the relay kickback current when it is turned off.  A 1N4007 is a high voltage rectifier diode and not really the best choice.  But, that's about right for a circuit you found on the internet somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the working,can you tell me how to connect relay.As it has 5 pins and only 2 of them are shown in diagram.Also where can i connect a buzzer or led for indication?I think i should connect it with relay but have no idea how.

Comment: The dashed line to the right of the relay coil goes to the relay contacts.  Think of a relay as an electrically-operated switch. You could connect a buzzer or LED either in place of the relay coil, or to the relay contacts.

Comment: Can you please specify in terms of pins like COIL COM NC NO.

Comment: @kstb: COIL refers to the electro-magnet that actuates the relay.  NC, COM, and NO are "normally closed", "common", and "normally open".  This describes a SPDT (single pole, double throw) switch.  COM is connected to either NC or NO, depending on whether the coil is energized.  When the rely is just sitting there with no power applied, COM is connected to NC.  As the name suggests, this connection is "normally closed", with normal referring to "coil unenergized".  When the coil is energized, COM is connected to NO instead of NC.